# CMake install dynamic generated list of files

Tags: cmake

I have a cmake project that upon installing it will invoke a python script which will output for me a list of files that I must also install.

I use this output and pass it to FILE(INSTALL ${output}) but this command doesnt put the files at the right place.

How can I install a list of file that is a output of a command? (Note that the command depends on the built target)

Answer (score 0):

Make a target which generates this list to get it during the build step. With the list of files written somewhere, use `install(SCRIPT <file>)` to run a CMake script which uses the file to copy/modify/whatever the files into the right place. The script itself will likely need to have `configure_file` used to get the install directory and the generated file path correct (I don't see a way to pass arguments to the cmake command which runs the script).